# How to integrate API Gateway with s3 in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

The docs are very clear in doing this in the console, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html, but replicating in CDK is really painful.

My question is how to create an Rest API backed with s3 (no lambda in the middle) in CDK, or at least how the apigateway.AwsIntegration works.

I've tried many things and realized that I was coding blind.
I have made already multiple integrations between restApi, lambda, sqs, dynamoDB, s3 and all of them were so easy. But integrating API Gateway with S3 directly is about to make me cry.

I need that a restAPI store the request payload directly to an S3 bucket.

This is what I already tried:

Add a policy stament to RestApi:

```js
const apiResourcePolicy = new iam.PolicyDocument({
        statements: [
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ['s3:Put*'],            
            resources: [bucket.bucketName],
            principals: [new ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com')]
          })          
        ]
      });
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "dispatch-api", {
        restApiName: "my api name",
        description: "api description",
        policy: apiResourcePolicy        
      });
```

I thought that this should be enough to solve permissions issues, but when I added the AWS Integration to the API, like this:

```js
const getS3Integration = new apigateway.AwsIntegration({
        service: "s3",        
        path: bucket.bucketName,                               
      });

api.root.addMethod("PUT", getS3Integration, {
    requestValidator: requestValidator,
    requestModels: {"application/json": myModel},
  });
```

I'm getting:

```
1:41:11 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ApiGateway::Method           | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Role ARN must be specified for AWS integrations (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Proxy:
null)
```

I don't know how to specify that Role ARN, I did not found that in the docs. Don't know either if add policy to restAPI was necessary. I was trying to replicate the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) in CDK.

Comment: You should consider sharing what you have already tried so we can help you better.

Comment: @Andre.IDK I update the post. Anything else just tell.

Comment: I want to say that doing this is very painful indeed, it makes me cry as well when I try and try and try and nothing works. I do feel that implementing this in code is unnecessarily convoluted. Never did I struggle so much before coding stuff in general. Thanks for posting this question, though. The answer guided me in the right direction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following is not the full set, but this should give you some ideas. I did similar things on SQS, I cried too back then

```js
    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'storage');

    const executeRole = new iam.Role(this, "role", {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com'),
      path: "/service-role/"
    });

    bucket.grantReadWrite(executeRole);

    const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 's3api');

    const s3Integration = new apigateway.AwsIntegration({
      service: 's3',
      integrationHttpMethod: "PUT",
      path: "{bucket}",
      options : {
        credentialsRole: executeRole,
        // should have all kind of path mapping..        
      }
    })

    api.root.addResource("{folder}").addMethod("PUT", s3Integration, {
      methodResponses: [
        {
          statusCode: "200"
        }
      ]});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the document you linked (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html), section "Set up IAM permissions for the API to invoke Amazon S3 actions", the policy you need to use is totally different from what you encoded.

Your policy, if applied to a bucket, would say: if the request is from the service "api gateway", allow `put:*` actions. This approach is for other use cases.

According to the documentation, you need:

- create a role
- the role should contain policies:

  1. allowed actions (`put:*` in your case)
  2. allow api gateway to switch to the role.
- use the role in `apigateway.RestApi`

The policy (1) should be obvious, the (2) as given in the documentation is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems to me that you are **not providing IAM role** for your integration. You are providing a [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html#cfn-apigateway-restapi-policy) for `RestApi` only which is a **resource-based policy** for your API. In other words, it does not apply to your integrations, but rather specifies who can execute your API. Generally you don't use it if you want to make your API public.

For AWS integration, you should be providing IAM role with **S3 permissions** using [IntegrationOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.IntegrationOptions.html). Specifically, through `credentials` option:

> An IAM role that **API Gateway assumes**.

The CloudFormation docs, which CDK maps into, have [more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-credentials) on integration `Credentials`:

> The credentials that are required for the integration. To specify an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that API Gateway assumes, specify the role's Amazon Resource Name (ARN). To require that the caller's identity be passed through from the request, specify arn:aws:iam::*:user/*.

> To use resource-based permissions on the AWS Lambda (Lambda) function, don't specify this property. Use the AWS::Lambda::Permission resource to permit API Gateway to call the function. For more information, see Allow Amazon API Gateway to Invoke a Lambda Function in the AWS Lambda Developer Guide.